# Column Chart of Google Chart doesn't center

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

View code

```
$.getJSON('Transacciones/getData',{}, function (data) {
    dataModulo3 = data;
    dibujarColumnChart( transformarData(data) , "divModulo3");
});
```

Controller , I get data from this

```
public ActionResult getData(){
    List<String[]> aux = new List<String[]>();
    aux.Add(new String[] { "string", "number", "number", "number", "number",   "number", "number" });//tipo cabeceras
    aux.Add(new String[] { "Year", "Austria", "Belgium", "Czech Republic", "Finland", "France", "Germany" });//nombre cabeceras
    aux.Add(new String[] { "2003", "1336060", "3817614", "974066", "21104797", "6651824", "15727003"});
    return Json(aux, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

transformarData js function bellow

```
function transformarData(data) {
    var rows = data.length;
    var cols = data[0].length;
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        tdata.addColumn(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
    }
    tdata.addRows(data.length);
    for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {    
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var value = data[i][j];
            if (data[0][j] == 'number') {
                value = parseInt(data[i][j]);
            }
        tdata.setCell(i, j, value);
        }
    }
    return tdata;
}
```

dibujarColumnChart function js bellow

```
function dibujarColumnChart(datos, idDiv) {
    var data = datos;
    var columnchart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(idDiv));
    columnchart.draw(data, {
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
    });
}
```

[image: Not center column chart]

But if instead of using data from controller I use javascript data :

```
$.getJSON('Transacciones/getData',dataJson , function (data) {
    dataModulo3 = data;
    var datajs = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003]
    ]);
    dibujarColumnChart( datajs , "divModulo3");
});
```

I get column chart centered:

[image: column chart centered]

I want to know if I can center this column chart that get data from json call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used tdata.setCell(i, j, value) instead of tdata.setCell(i - 2, j , value) so you didn't give values to the first fow. Instead, google created a row, that's why it moves to the right. Also, you should add 1 row instead of 3 rows.

See the piece of code below:

```
function transformarData(data) {
    var rows = data.length-2;
    var cols = data[0].length;
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    log("creado tdata");
    //tdata.addColumn(data[, data[0][0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        tdata.addColumn(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
    }
    tdata.addRows(rows);
    for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var value = data[i][j];
            if (data[0][j] == 'number') {
                value = parseInt(data[i][j]);
            }
            tdata.setCell(i-2, j, value);
        }
    }
    return tdata;
}
```

PD: For other posts please try to name your variables in English for better understanding of everybody who want's to answer your question.